# Nvidia Drivers do not load

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I can't get the drivers to work in Ubuntu. When running `lshw` I get this output:

```
root@ubuntu-hp:/home/tryfon# lshw -c video
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a3000000-a3ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:a4080000-a40fffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:157 memory:a2000000-a2ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff.
```

In the configuration line for nvidia, there should be a "driver: " thing I guess. It 's highly possible that I messed it up by trying to fix a huge vsync-tearing problem I had with the monitor. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by editing `/etc/default/grub`.
Remove the `nomodeset` option from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and then `sudo grub-update`.

After reboot your second monitor should work.